# More than 3 branch point Dessign d' enfant

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, combinatorial-geometry, several-complex-variables

I wanted read about Dessign d' enfants most of the reference define it as 
(X,D) where X is compact orientable surface and D is the bipartite graph with some properties that is there is  a bijection with covering map over $\mathbb{P}^1$ having $0,1,\infty$ as branch point. 
       I want to know if there is an immediate generalisation with $\mathbb{P}^1$ having any finite number of branch point. Please give a reference. 
        The result I am chasing is some this like this if for the three point case let $\sigma_0$ , $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_{\infty}$ are the ramification profile for the over $0,1,\infty$ and $\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_{\infty}=id$ then there is a dessign corresponding to this data and its a bipartite graph, so is it true that if we increase the branch point say 4 branch point the dessign will look like tripartite graph ?

Comment: The word is `Dessins d'enfants`.

Answer (score 1):

Grothendieck has defined Dessins d'enfants to study non singular  curves defined over $\bar Q$ the algebraic closure of $Q$, it turns out that Belyi has shown that for such a curve $C$, there is always a map $f:C\rightarrow P^1C$ ramified at at most 3 points, so there is no need to study the situation where the number of branch points is stricly superior to 3.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belyi%27s_theorem